# Problems passing form feedback between controllers to re-display a form error message

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Controller A shows some data and displays a form.

The form submits to Controller B.

When form errors are found in Controller B, the form needs to be re-displayed by Controller A.

To do this requires a `return redirect "blah"` in Controller A.

To pass the errors back to Controller A using a redirect, I can set the error message in the model:

```
model.put("errormsg", "look what happened");
```

This has the annoying effect of putting the entire text of the error message into the URL:

```
/controllera/somemethod?errormsg=look+what+happened
```

However, even though I see the text on the URL, when I try to display it from the JSTL, nothing is shown:

```
<c:out value="${errormsg}"/>
```

Is there a better approach to all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better approach to all of this?

IMHO better approach is to use standard scheme: controller A shows form, data submitted to controller A and if error occurs controller A display errors. If data valid controller A do redirect to controller B.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend:

1. Modify Controller A to accept the HttpServletRequest.
2. Put the error message in the request as an attribute: `req.setAttribute("errormsg", "look what happened");`

The JSTL output should work just fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Place this on your JSP:

```
<c:out value="${param.errormsg}" />
```