# Returning on the form when the validation is completed and keeping the value on the input field

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, controller

I am writing Web application and trying to integrate Spring Web MVC 3.0 framework. I want to validate input field from XHTML page. The form (what holds one input field) submitted, but then the page is redirected. If you explicitly redirect to the same form (registration.htm) the value entered in the input field disappears, what is not al right. I want the value stay in the input field.
This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserNameController 
{
    @InitBinder()
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new UserNameValidator());
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="userName.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView userName(@Valid @RequestParam("uName") String uName)
    { System.out.println("__________________________ "+ uName);
     return new ModelAndView("registration");
    }  

  public class UserNameValidator implements Validator 
  {
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) 
    {
       return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

     public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
     {
         System.out.println("=======================");
         User user = (User) target;
         ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "uName", "field.required", "Required field");
         if(!errors.hasFieldErrors("uName"))
         {
          //   if(user.existUser() == true)
            // {

             //}
         }

     }
  }


}
```

Validation does not work either. What is the way to get back on the form what would keep entered value?
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
What is the way to get back on the form what would keep entered value?
```

Do redirect only when you successfully register user, and just return him to registration page when validation fails.

See also: [Problems passing form feedback between controllers to re-display a form error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931354/problems-passing-form-feeback-between-controllers-to-re-display-a-form-error-mess)

Comment: When the value is entered into the input field it is submitted for validation and controller automatically kicks me on the page RequestMapper is using, i.e. RequestMapping("userName.htm"). Then you see HTTP 404 errors. So then I forced the controller push me on registration page where the form is  being filled in. Though entered value on the input field is removed. What are your solutions, please?

Comment: There is no GET request, only POST. Below is the code from XHTML page which invokes the controller above:`code <tr>      
    <form id="userName" action="userName.htm" method="post" accept="text/plain" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
         
        <td>
        <label for> User Name: 
        </td> 
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="uName" maxlength="20" size="40" onmouseout="submitUName()"/> </p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>*</td>
        </form>       
    </tr>  code`

Comment: I figured out myself. The main thing what was missing is value="${user}" snippet of code in XHTML code. Likewise I needed model.addAttribute("user", user); I wasted a lot of time on this......

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself. The main thing what was missing is `value="${user}"` snippet of code in XHTML code. Likewise I needed `model.addAttribute("user", user);` I wasted a lot of time on this......